# Get selectedvalue from an ASP.NET dynamically-generated DropDownList

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I generate an `ASP.NET` `DropDownList` items in `javascript` with this piece of code:

```
FilteredCategories.forEach(function(cat) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = cat.Name;
    opt.innerHTML = cat.Name;
    document.getElementById('CategoryDDL').appendChild(opt);
});
```

Everything is fine and items are shown in the DropDown, but when I click submit button there are no items bound to the DropDown. I mean if I run the following code in `code behind` I'll get 0:

```
int ItemsCount = CategoryDDL.Items.Count; //Result is 0
```

Please help me because I need to get the selected value of DropDown during postback.

Thanx in advance

Comment: If you populate the list from js, asp.net does not know it. One thing you can do is: have an asp hidden field in your mark up. Then before submitting the form, populate the field with selected value; and in code behind, read the hidden field.

Comment: @mshsayem I'm exactly using this solution right now but because of some scenarios it's become a little complicated. So I wondered if there was a better way. I'm wondering why Request["CategoryDDL"] also doesn't work!?

Comment: Items in the drop-down-list are _remembered_ by the `ViewState`. As you are not modifying that, asp.net does not know items were inserted (by js).